# ns2 installation and compilation

Tags: installation, ns2

I run ns-2.35 on my Ubuntu 12.10

While I finished installing my ns2 and tried to run via "sudo ns xxx.tcl", it showed on the screen saying that there was no ns2 on my computer and I have to use "apt-get install ns2". I used it, and then it was installed successfully.

Now I modify some .cc files and recompile my ns2, and it is successful, too.

But the problem is that the results are not modified as I want. In fact, the result doesn't change. It seems my modification doesn't really change anything in my ns2. Why? There's no error in my installation or compilation? I am so confused. Is there anyone face the same problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your installed ns2 is not in your bash_profile path. execute **which ns** in terminal. it displays which ns is currently working. If it is usr/bin its default ns .now give path to your ns using **PATH** command. hope it helps

Comment: Yes, it's usr/bin/ns. Thanks so much for this. But for modifying the path, I have modified the path setting in .bashrc file, and the path was not set to default path. Do I need to change it?

Comment: Go to your NS2allinone/bin directory Type "pwd" it displays (echo) the path to present bin folder.now copy this and open new terminal and type .bash_profile just add this path with existing path.           or PATH="your pwd echo message" now tou can execute your ns.. but you need to do this for every terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For compiling your changes go to these steps:
1. firstly in terminal goto your ns2.XX folder then do following commands
2. make clean
3../configure
4.make
5.sudo make install 
6.close terminal and open it again
7. run your tcl scripts.

hope it helps ..!! Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

1) Download 'ns-allinone-2.35' from :
  http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsnam/files/allinone/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz/download

2) Extract the downloaded zip file 'ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz file' to desktop.

3) Now you need to download some essential packages for ns2,these packages can be downloaded by using the following command : applications>accessories>terminal or dashhome>trminal
then type the below line on the terminal window

```
     "sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev libtool gcc"

     or type this command

     "sudo apt-get install autoconf automake gcc g++ build-essential libxmu-dev libtool libxt-dev"
```

4) Now change your directory(here i have already extracted the downloaded files to desktop,so my location is desktop) type the following codes in the command window to install NS2.

```
     cd Desktop   
     cd ns-allinone-2.35
     ./install

                          The installation procedure will take a few minutes..........
```

5) After compleating the installation type the following command in the command window

```
      gedit ~/.bashrc
```

6) Now an editor window appears,please copy and paste the follwing codes in the end of the text file (note that '/home/abhiram/Desktop/ns-allinone-2.35/octl-1.14' in each line in the below code should be replaced with your location where the 'ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz'file is extracted)

```
  # LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  OTCL_LIB=/home/abhiram/Desktop/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14
  NS2_LIB=/home/abhiram/Desktop/ns-allinone-2.35/lib
  X11_LIB=/usr/X11R6/lib
  USR_LOCAL_LIB=/usr/local/lib
  export            LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$OTCL_LIB:$NS2_LIB:$X11_LIB:$USR_LOCAL_LIB

 # TCL_LIBRARY
 TCL_LIB=/home/abhiram/Desktop/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library
 USR_LIB=/usr/lib
 export TCL_LIBRARY=$TCL_LIB:$USR_LIB

 # PATH
 XGRAPH=/home/abhiram/Desktop/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/home/abhiram/Desktop/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/abhiram/Desktop/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix
 NS=/home/abhiram/Desktop/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/
 NAM=/home/abhiram/Desktop/ns-allinone-2.35/nam-1.15/
 PATH=$PATH:$XGRAPH:$NS:$NAM
```

7) Save and close the text editor and then type the following command on the terminal

```
   source ~/.bashrc
```

8) Close the terminal window and start a new terminal window and now change the directory to ns-2.35 and validate ns-2.35 by exicuting the following command ( it takes 30 to 45 minutes)

```
    cd ns-2.35
    ./validate
```

9) If the installation is successful, then you will be able to see % at the command prompt while typing the following command

```
    ns
```

10) Now type

```
    exit
```